# How much time does it take one to build the trie

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, trie

There is a lot of information in the literature which says that the time to search a trie is O(N) where N is the length of the pattern.

However, building the tree will also take some time. To me, let's say there are X words with a total of Y characters.

So then O(Y) is the time (because we have to insert each character). Is this assessment correct (I am usually not correct)

Comment: Insertion time x elements to insert. Off the top of my head O(nlogn).

Answer (score 1):

> So then O(Y) is the time (because we have to insert each character)

Sure, you have to process each input character, and either follow an existing branch or insert a new char.

It can't be faster then O(Y), since you have to look at each input char. There's neither sorting nor any other operation which could make it slower.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong.  Creating a trie and searching a trie are two different algorithms.  One wouldn't build a trie, search it, then throw away the entire data structure.

Comment: You're right in that a trie should be used many times. However, your answer is wrong, since you claim the OP is wrong.